# How can I factory reset a Namecheap server?

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, namecheap

One of my Namecheap shared-hosting servers is badly messed up. The database, files, etc, are all deleted or screwed up and PHPMyAdmin doesn't even work anymore.

Rather than to try to fix this by hand I'd like to nuke the whole server and start fresh. I found a [GoDaddy help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/start-over-erase-all-content-9182) that tells how to do it on their servers, but Namecheap doesn't seem to have an equivalent document.

How can I reset the entire thing?

Comment: Do you mean the entire server or just your account on that server

Comment: Simple... contact them and have them delete your account :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed the matter with Namecheap's staff through their [Live Chat feature](https://www.namecheap.com/support/live-chat/general.aspx).

Apparently Namecheap doesn't let users do this by themselves. You have to get in touch with a member of the Hosting team (via Live Chat, for example) and they'll do it for you. The reset takes about 10 minutes and after that they'll send you the new cPanel credentials by email.

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting accounts usually do not have much ability to alter the settings of a server, because those altered settings effect everyone else that is also sharing the server. VPS and dedicated servers may allow you to clean state them.

You can delete all of the files on your server through FTP. But in order to modify your MySQL you will likely need access to PHPMyAdmin or command line. If this doesn't seem possible to you then I think using your webhosting's support is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The best way this can be done is by contacting them to do the work for you to avoid mistakes. I factory reset a client site with them a few days ago.